# JQuery UI datepicker not sitting over dropdowns in IE 6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, datepicker, drop-down-menu

For some reason our datepicker is falling behind the dropdowns below it in IE6

[www.senegal.co.uk](http://www.senegal.co.uk/)

Every search I have done seems to suggest the datepicker should deal with this.

We do have the following css in place:

```
.ui-datepicker-cover {
    display: none; /*sorry for IE5*/
    display/**/: block; /*sorry for IE5*/
    position: absolute; /*must have*/
    z-index: -1; /*must have*/
    filter: mask(); /*must have*/
    top: -4px; /*must have*/
    left: -4px; /*must have*/
    width: 200px; /*must have*/
    height: 200px; /*must have*/
}
```

I have tried adding bgiframe and calling:

> $("#ui-datepicker-div").bgIframe();

But it doesn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

I'm thinking we're going to need someone with experience using jquery ui datepicker to help us out on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution to this in time, so in the end just put in some code to hide the dropdowns

```
beforeShow: function() {
    $('.searchPanelGroup6').css('visibility', 'hidden');
},
onClose: function() {
    $('.searchPanelGroup6').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need BGIFrame - http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe

Comment: Have tried $("#ui-datepicker-div").bgIframe();  but it doesn't seem to solve the issue...

Comment: it's all lower case: $('#ui-datepicker-div').bgiframe();

Answer (score 2):

The quickest and easiest way around this would be to use the [BGIFrame](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe) plugin which should get around your issue with IE6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a z-index bug with IE6. I have seen this issue before but never had to use it with jQuery. Here are a couple of links to help you out in the right direction.

[Link1](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/2009/02/03/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)
[Link2](http://jquerybox.com/index.php?topic=14.0)

Answer (score 1):

try $("#datepickerid").bgiframe();

The bgiframe plugin is available at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe

It's used by the jQuery UI team in most places where they have such an issue.

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't  z-index: -1 send the layer to the **back** of the stack thus putting it under the form element?

I think you may need a positive value.

Comment: That CSS is what is provided by jquery ui and what everyone says to use.

Comment: Only if the form elements are positioned. In IE6, dropdowns are activex controls and don't obey z-index anyway.

Answer (score 0):

we're not using explicit positioning that much, so for me it recently worked to apply the following style directly to the selects/ dropdown elements that wouldn't hide below a datepicker:

`zoom: -1; position: relative;`

(oh, and it was applied in a separate style sheet which is used only for ms ie 6...)